# Correct usage of executeAsync of RESTSharp in a loop C#

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I am learning the correct usage of `executeAsync` method of RESTSharp and seems like am facing a memory leak due to incorrect disposing of RestRequests (probably):

```
var client = new RestClient("some_URL");

int count = 99999;

for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {

    var request = new RestRequest("some_link", Method.GET);
    request.AddParameter("some_param", i.toString());

    client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
    {
        some_callback_function(response.content);

        request = null;
        response = null;
    }

}
```

If I let this code run the memory of my app keeps increasing and doesn't seem to be garbage collected.

What is the proper way to handle `ExecuteAsync`'s responses and dispose the objects afterwards?